# Hive : Query Table with column name having a keyword and a space

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table test. It has a column 'abc group'
I want to have a query
select `abc group`,sum(someothercolumn)
from test group by `abc group`

Even with using backticks (`), query fails. hive starts to consider group in the column name as group keyword

Comment: Try double quotes.  That usually works in most databases:  `"abc group"`.

Comment: in this case if i use double quotes in select statement, it just returns "abc group"....but not the values...using ticks work if there is only space but no keyword in the column name....since here there is both that is creating the isste

Answer (score 0):

include **backticks(`)** in group by clause also.

i have tried below queries by recreating your scenario

```
hive> select * from so;
+------------+------+--+
| abc group  | sal  |
+------------+------+--+
| abc        | 10   |
| def        | 20   |
| abc        | 20   |
| def        | 30   |
+------------+------+--+
```

Now i'm trying to do group by on **abc group**
column and **sum(sal)**

```
hive> select `abc group`,sum(sal) sum from so group by `abc group`;
+------------+------+--+
| abc group  | sum  |
+------------+------+--+
| abc        | 30   |
| def        | 50   |
+------------+------+--+
```

***Scenario1:-***
If you enclose your abc group column in **single (or) double quotes** then hive consider them as string literal values and the results will be different when we compared with backticks(`).

```
hive> select "abc group",sum(sal) sum from so group by "abc group";
+------------+------+--+
|    _c0     | sum  |
+------------+------+--+
| abc group  | 80   |
+------------+------+--+
```

so in the above example i have enclosed abc group in double quotes hive consider as string and did group by so the sum(sal) is **80**.

***Scenario2:-***
in this scenario group by on abc group column but in select having "abc group" value.

```
  hive> select "abc group",sum(sal) sum from so group by `abc group`;
    +------------+------+--+
    |    _c0     | sum  |
    +------------+------+--+
    | abc group  | 30   |
    | abc group  | 50   |
    +------------+------+--+
```

hive did group by based on abc group column data but in select we haven't mentioned abc group with **backticks(`)** but we kept string value("abc group") in it. so for both groups having same value for _c0 column.

Comment: scenario1 and scenario2 does not solve my problem...so the abc group column has many distinct values.....i need corresponding sum for each of them...using just ticks fails

Comment: 1.2.1.....this is present in the hdinsight cluster (3.6) which i am using

Comment: looks like Bug in hdinsight as i have tried all my hive queries on HDP-2.5 and Hive 1.2.1.Please contact the hdinsight support regarding this issue..